# How can I set $PATH for awesome window manager prompt

Tags: awesome

I'm using awesome 3.5.9 in Debian Testing. `/bin/bash` is my user's shell. My `~/.profile` reads

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  # include .bashrc if it exists
  if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
  fi
fi
```

And in my `~/.bashrc` I have edited my `$PATH` to contain some custom directories.

In awesome's `rc.lua`, I have set up the prompt like this:

```
awful.key({ modkey }, "r",
  function ()
    awful.prompt.run({ prompt = "Run: " },
      mypromptbox[mouse.screen].widget,
      awful.util.spawn, awful.completion.bash)
end),
```

However, the auto-completion in the awesome prompt doesn't consider the custom directories I have in my `$PATH`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/637799/awesome-does-not-recognize-path-change

Comment: Thanks, but that answer refers to zsh, and recommends using `.zshenv` to set the `$PATH`. Bash doesn't have this file. I found references to a `BASH_ENV` variable which I can use to give the name of a file to be sourced in non-interactive shells, but I have no clue where to set this ...